# SharePoint 2019 permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, 2019

I met the following strange behavior of SharePoint 2019.

Given list named A, and some existing list items: A1, A2, A3... List A is shared to a big user group which contain U1, U2, U3, U4.

List items A1, A2, A3 are shared with unique permission to users U1, U2, U3, U4 (not inherit permission from list A anymore).

If one day, I add U1, U2, U3, U4 to list A's permission, then:

- Remove U1, U2 from list A's permission
- Change rights of U3, U4
  ---> U1, U2 will disappear from permission of list items A1, A2, A3 while U3, U4 still remain.

Is there anyone who have experience about that scenario? I wonder if it is feature of Sharepoint 2019 or an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by default.

When you remove one user (you ever directly grant permissions for him/her) from List permission, the following message will be prompted.

[image]

Removing the user's permission from list permissions will remove all permissions on the List including unique permissions which were granted directly to the user.

As the users still are in the shared group, so they should be able to access the content of the list shared to the group, but you cannot see the users list in the list permissions as they are not shared directly.

Hope the above is clear.

Comment: Dear Kally. Thanks for your information. We used sharepoint 2007 before and did not meet this issue. Is that behavior a new way which Sharepoint do with user permission? That way, can I understand that we can only add, change user of the list, should not remove cause we have many list items with different permissions below?

Comment: I have no SharePoint 2007, so cannot test on the version. But I tested on SharePoint 2013, it is same behavior with SharePoint 2019, seem to be by default since SharePoint 2013.If you have many list items with unique permissions, we suggest you remove users from related items, not list/library permission level in case it may affect other items,

Comment: Thank Kally for your advice. Is there any way we can prevent that behavior or a better way to do? We allow user to change permission of list item to prevent unrelated user to read specific items, but sometime users mess-up our list permission by mistake.

Comment: no, per my know, there is no better way.